# NetSuite custom field according template

Tags: netsuite

Question about custom field in Netsuite. I want to have a text field in the Inventory item form which has to match some rules. The rules are: 
1. Text width is 11 (that one is easy)
2. First 4 symbols must be letters, with exception that the 4th symbol is "U" always.
3. The last 7 symbols must be the digits.

Is there any chance to acheive this without any scripting or programming? Also I think it would be acceptable to have an additional field which says that another field is OK (according the rules above) or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your validation rules with the regular expression `^[A-Za-z]{3}U\d{7}$`

This means:

- `^` - start at the beginning of the string
- `[A-Za-z]{3}` - match the character set A-Z and a-z, exactly 3 times
- `U` - match the character "U"
- `\d{7}` - match a digit exactly 7 times
- `$` - assert we are at the end of the string now

You can use this regex in a workflow formula to return an error if the condition is not met:

`NOT REGEXP_LIKE({itemid}, '^[A-Za-z]{3}U\d{7}$')`

[image]